# I can't make new line with "\n" on JDA

Tags: java, discord-jda

first time I am asking for help in here so If my thread format is wrong I am so sorry.My problem is I can't make new line in Java JDA(Java Discord API).

When I use:

`eb.setDescription("For \n Example");`

It works just fine but I am trying to do this.

First I am getting string from config file:

`String Message = plugin.getConfig().getString("Discord." + "PrivateMessage")`

It gets the String fine but when I use `eb.setDescription(Message);`
Message coming without lines. There are new line brackets "\n" in message but they are not making new lines.Message coming like:

"For \n Example" without new lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your actual string is in a file and you just read it out. When you put `\n` in a file that doesn't automatically convert to a newline when you read it. You can do `string = string.replace("\\n", "\n")` to convert it.